# How to change the img src of a td on the closest tr selection and to hover on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>sdh</td>
        <td>228285486</td>
        <td>06/18/15 17:11:53</td>
        <td>07/12/16 08:46:55</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class="open_chat"><img src="img/open.png"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>dsf</td>
        <td>2248285486</td>
        <td>06/18/15 17:11:53</td>
        <td>07/12/16 08:46:55</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td><img src="img/open.png"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>sdfhs</td>
        <td>2248285486</td>
        <td>06/18/15 17:11:53</td>
        <td>07/12/16 08:46:55</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td><img src="img/open.png"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: And your jQuery code ? That you tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `find()`

```
$('tr').hover(function(){
var newurl = 'http://new.url';
$(this).find('img').attr('src',newurl);
});
```

to set the old url use a mouseleave event

```
$('tr').mouseleave(function(){ 
$(this).find('img').attr('src', 'old_src.jpg');
 });
```

you can use a custom attribute to save the old src and get it back when you trigger the mouseleave event

Comment: thanks and how to make it change back when not hovered over

Comment: use a mouseleave or mouseout event

Comment: don't forget to click de green button to accept the answer :p

Comment: what part is not working ,the hover or the mouseleave?

Comment: is your javascript disabled on ie10?

Comment: active scripting is enabled

Comment: what version of jquery are you using, are you sure that you don't have any console errors?

Comment: jquery version 1.12.3 and no console errors. Both of your code are very similar, i used yours

Comment: strange this should work, it may be a css problem where a div is overlapping the intended element and the events don't fire,another question: is your code in  a document ready statement?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your script:

```
$('tr').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'new_src.jpg');
});
```

Comment: $('tr').mouseout(function(){
   $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'old_src.jpg');
});